# How to read an integer from a byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a byte array, and I would like to read an integer from this array. How can I do it?

Something like this:

```
 int i;

 tab = new byte[32];

 i = readint(tab,0,3); // i = int from tab[0] to tab[3] (int = 4 bytes?)

 i = readint(tab,4,7);
```

etc...

Answer (score 16):

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
```

Ref: [How to: Convert a byte Array to an int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx)

Comment: Although performance wise, it would be better to have two separate classes for Big and Little endian, instead of reversing the array every time. Furthermore, since the OP's original question has an array of 4 ints, individual 4-byte words would have to be reversed. And since system architecture is known in advance, OOP approach would make much more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Also, there is a class called `Endian` in Jon Skeet's [miscutil library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) which implements conversion methods between a byte array and various primitive types, taking endianness into account.

For your question, usage would be something like:

```
// Input data
byte[] tab = new byte[32];

// Pick the appropriate endianness
Endian endian = Endian.Little;

// Use the appropriate endian to convert
int a = endian.ToInt32(tab, 0);
int b = endian.ToInt32(tab, 4);
int c = endian.ToInt32(tab, 8);
int d = endian.ToInt32(tab, 16);
...
```

A simplified version of the Endian class would be something like:

```
public abstract class Endian
{
    public short ToInt16(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((short)FromBytes(value, startIndex, 2));
    }

    public int ToInt32(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        return unchecked((int)FromBytes(value, startIndex, 4));
    }

    public long ToInt64(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        return FromBytes(value, startIndex, 8);
    }

    // This same method can be used by int16, int32 and int64.
    protected virtual long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len);
}
```

And then the `FromBytes` abstract method is implemented differently for each endian type.

```
public class BigEndian : Endian
{
    protected override long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
        {
            ret = unchecked((ret << 8) | buffer[startIndex+i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

public class LittleEndian : Endian
{
    protected override long FromBytes(byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int len)
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
        {
            ret = unchecked((ret << 8) | buffer[startIndex+len-1-i]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be great if there was also some code for producing the bytes from the integer here. Otherwise (in most cases) someone cannot use this code without guessing that part. :(

Answer (score 4):

You could use `BitConverter.ToInt32`. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it manually, something like that should do the trick!

```
byte[] data = ...;
int startIndex = 0;
int value = data[startIndex];

for (int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
  value <<= 8;
  value |= data[i+startIndex];
}
```